# layout_gravity doesnt work

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout with 7 buttons, I want 6 of them centered in the screen and the last one at bottom.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/account_but"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/accountDesc"
            android:src="@drawable/boton_usos" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/alquilar_but"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/alquilarDesc"
            android:src="@drawable/boton_alquilar" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/paradas_but"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/paradasDesc"
            android:src="@drawable/boton_paradas" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/noticias_but"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/noticiasDesc"
            android:src="@drawable/boton_noticias" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/incidencia_but"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/incidenciaDesc"
            android:src="@drawable/boton_incidencia" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/informacion_but"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/infoDesc"
            android:src="@drawable/boton_informacion" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sabadell_but"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/banner_sabadell"
            android:contentDescription="@string/infoDesc" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

With this code, I got the buttons start at left top.

How can I fix it?

Comment: can you show image picture how actually want ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  `android:gravity` instead of `layout_gravity`.

```
 <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
          >
```

I implement it and It is working.

**EDIT:**

I put Entire XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/account_but"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
            android:text="Button 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/alquilar_but"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:text="Button 2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/paradas_but"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:text="Button 3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/noticias_but"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:text="Button 4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/incidencia_but"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:text="Button 5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/informacion_but"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:text="Button 6" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sabadell_but"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:text="Button 7" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And Output.

[image]

Comment: so, I should write both, I get the first part centered, but not the last one at bottom

Answer (score 2):

Try this: Use  **android:gravity="center"** insted of  **android:layout_gravity="center"**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/background"
>

  <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
         android:gravity="center"
      >

  <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/account_but"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/accountDesc"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/boton_usos" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/alquilar_but"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/alquilarDesc"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/boton_alquilar" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/paradas_but"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/paradasDesc"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/boton_paradas" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/noticias_but"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/noticiasDesc"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/boton_noticias" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/incidencia_but"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/incidenciaDesc"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/boton_incidencia" />

     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/informacion_but"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/infoDesc"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/boton_informacion" /> 

    </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      >     

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sabadell_but"
            android:background="@drawable/banner_sabadell"
            android:contentDescription="@string/infoDesc"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>  

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving you the my full XML file, as i had worked on it in my app

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_mainscreen">




  <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/lnrContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"        
        android:orientation="vertical" >

 <Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnRecipe"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="80dip"
    android:background="@string/RecipeButton_background"/>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnIngredients"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="80dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:background="@string/IngredientButton_background"/>


<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="80dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:background="@string/MenuButton_background" />

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnShoppingList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="80dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:background="@string/ShoppingListButton_background"/>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnSynctoServer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="80dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:text="Synchronize"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:background="@string/ShoppingListButton_background"/>

</LinearLayout>

  <Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnSynctoServer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Synchronize"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dip"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```