# How to keep the button static in UI

Tags: android-layout, android

**1)** 
I have this UI where the button at the bottom of the screen must be static when the soft keyboard appears. i.e now it comes as

**BEFORE**

[image: before choosing DR]

**AFTER**

[image: After choosing DR]

**2)**
while on soft keyboard when I press enter the next edit text field must come into focus .
(i.e) while on K1 and I press enter the focus must shift to K2 and must be visible.

**EDIT**
This is how i get edit text field

```
dr_e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.dr_editText);
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(dr_e.getWindowToken(), 0);
            k1_e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.k1_editText);
            k2_e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.k2_editText);
            al_e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.al_editText);
            alconst_e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.al_const_editText);
```

Comment: @chintan khetiya is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason why the next edit text field focussed, was not able to be viewed was because of the result button popping up whenever the soft keyboard appears. to that use

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

in onCreate() method of the class.

Comment: this is as same as android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"  to the activity entry in androidmanifext.xml as i had said in the comment. Anyways do accept the answer if ur query is solved.

Comment: @jagz87 ya but directly i cant accept your answer but upvoted that particular comment.

Answer (score 2):

To show Soft Keyboard for EditText:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEdit);
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
// only will trigger it if no physical keyboard is open
mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

To hide Soft Keyboard for EditText:

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

See more

Refer this links: http://www.androidpeople.com/android-hide-virtual-keyboard-through-code/ , [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Comment: how to keep the result button at button not coming above softkeyboard?

Comment: have you set that gravity as bottom ?

Comment: there is no gravity  property for button view defined

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496236/layout-gravity-doesnt-work/15496335#15496335

Comment: but still the result button scrolls up :(

Comment: that's way, your button is coming up. if you want to keep button as static then you need to hide your keyboard.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27153/discussion-between-ahambrahmaasmi-and-chintan-khetiya)

Answer (score 2):

For defining which view should get next focus(say next focus to the view below) try the next

[android:nextFocusDown](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3anextFocusDown). For the complete guide search for the section ["Focus Handling](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)"

Now the next part, at the last edit text i.e the one before the button you will want the "enter" button on the soft keyboard to directly act as the Result button. For that set [onEditorActionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html) and override the onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) method. check if the actionId is actionSend and programmatically click your "Result" button.

For this your last edittext should have the property android:imeOptions="actionSend" and for programmatically clicking the button use Button.performCLick()

Comment: the thing is i am able to focus down but due to RESULT button appearing above soft keyboard the focused edittext field is not visible unless it is scrolled

Comment: two options : (1)either add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" so that the edittext which is in focus will come just above the soft keyboard. (2) have your screen layout inside a Scrollview and let the user scroll up in case the edittext hides.

Comment: but still the result button scrolls up :( i dont want result button to scroll up while soft keyboard comes up

Comment: Why you want that? Are you sure your requirement is right?
But still if you do not want that remove the android:windowSoftInputMode property and just keep the scrollview

Answer (score 1):

Can You check this in your manifest file

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustUnspecified";
```

I ll give you adjustable size on window
and related values.

update:-

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext";
```

try this in your xml ,where is your first edittext there.like this

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext" />
```